# How can we use find() API to find a string in the page URL.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page URL and want to use `find()` API and find string present in the URL.

**Code:**

```
var pageURL = document.URL;

$(pageURL).find('ArticleID');
```

With above code, am getting an error:

```
need to find if the string ArticleID is present in the URL or not.
```

Is there a better way to do it than using `find()`?

Comment: Is this to determine the presence/value of a querystring item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find is a jQuery method used to find elements in the DOM, not in strings. You don't need jQuery for this, use indexOf:

```
if(document.URL.indexOf("ArticleID") >= 0) {
    // ArticleID exists in document.URL
}
```

indexOf returns the first position of the input string, or `-1` if it's not found.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var isContains = pageURL.indexOf('ArticleID') > -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (document.URL.indexOf('ArticleID') === -1) {
  // insert code
  }
```

Comment: that means ArticleID is not find

Comment: You should provide more documented answers

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selector).find(selector)
```

The JQuery `find` Method takes a selector and is not what you are looking for.

Take a look at the Javascript `indexOf` or `search`